# Function template for string and int in C++

Tags: c++, templates

I want to have a function template which takes a vector and an element and returns the position of this element in the vector. I want this function to be applicable for both int and std::string types. This is the function template definition:

```
template<class T>
int findElement(const vector<T> &vec, const T &ele)
{
    for(size_t i = 0; i < vec.size(); i++)
    {
        if(typeid(ele) == typeid(std::string))
        {
            if(ele.compare(vec[i]) == 0)
                return i;
        }
        else
        {
            if(ele == vec[i])
                return i;
        }
    }
    return -1;
}
```

As you can see, I am checking the types initially so that I can use the appropriate comparison method. This works fine when I call with std::string type parameters but it gives the following error when I use it with double type:

```
 error C2228: left of '.compare' must have class/struct/union
```

and

```
see reference to function template instantiation 'int findElement<double>(const std::vector<_Ty> &,const T &)' being compiled
```

How do I solve this issue?

Thanks,
Rakesh.

Comment: std::string has an == operator defined!

Comment: Alternative for searches - `iter = std::find(vec.begin(), vec.end(), ele);`?

Comment: Also, if you want two different behaviors - just write two different functions.  :-)

Comment: Btw, you shouldn't really use `int` for the size of a vector in general-purpose utility code. It's possible on a 64 bit machine for someone to create a vector whose size is larger than `INT_MAX`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You should *never* have to check `typeid` when using templates. `std::string` defines `==` in the expected manner, so use it!

```
template<class T>
int findElement(const vector<T> &vec, const T &ele)
{
    for(size_t i = 0; i < vec.size(); i++)
    {
        if(ele == vec[i])
            return i;
    }
    return -1;
}
```

In general, if you need to special-case your templated function for a particular type, use a *template specialization*:

```
template<class T>
int findElement(const vector<T> &vec, const T &ele) {
    for(size_t i = 0; i < vec.size(); i++) {
        if(ele == vec[i])
            return i;
    return -1;
}

template<>
int findElement<std::string>(const vector<std::string> &vec, const std::string &ele) {
    for(size_t i = 0; i < vec.size(); i++) {
        if(ele.compare(vec[i]) == 0)
            return i;
    }
    return -1;
}
```

Comment: +1 for not using typeid. Be sure to understand the difference between runtime and compile-time reflection mechanisms. Runtime reflection is usually not the way to go in C++.

Answer (score 7):

`std::string` has `operator ==`, however, if you want call different methods from `T` - you should specialize, or overload function. `Typeid` can't help, since it's runtime type identification.

Example of overloading

```
template<class T>
int findElement(const vector<T> &vec, const T &ele)
{
    for(size_t i = 0; i < vec.size(); i++)
    {
        if(ele == vec[i])
             return i;
    }
    return -1;
}

int findElement(const vector<string>& vec, const string& ele)
{
   for (size_t i = 0; i < vec.size(); ++i)
   {
      if (ele.compare(vec[i]) == 0)
          return i;
   }
   return -1;
}
```

also, you can use `function overloading` only for compare, since loop is the same.